# Number of posts since last visit

Tags: php

I have a website where people can make posts and follow other users. I have a sidebar that has a value that keeps track of the number of posts that have been posted since your last visit.

I'm stuck thinking of how I should handle this. Should I create an entirely new table in the database called `notifications` that would hold the user's id and the number of posts since last visit, should I just add a column in the existing user table for this value, or should I use an entirely different method?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just make a method in the Posts object that returns the number of posts since last visit and takes a user as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Think, which object this is a property of. In your case, the count will differ from user to user, so we might assume, it is a user property.

We could hang it on the last login, but this would give us a wrong count, if the user is logged in for a long period (The user doesn't want to know the count since his last login, but since his last activity!).

So the easiest way could be to add a field to the users table, that holds the last post ID - We just `SELECT MAX(id) FROM posts` and update users.lastSeenPost with the result on every user action. We can then display `MAX(post.id)-users.lastSeenPost` as the new post count.

Answer (score 0):

Every post has a date recording when it was made.

Every user will have a date keeping track of when he/she logged in the last time.

By the following SQL statement you could ask the database to return the number of posts since the user logged in last:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `posts` WHERE `posts.post_date` > `user.lastlogin_date`
```

Comment: Most people don't log out of websites anymore though, so wouldn't this only work for when they actually log in?

Comment: This shows the count of new posts since the user logged in, not since his last action! If the user is logged in for hours, this can be wrong by orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Bagwell please specify 'last visit' then :-) Could mean last login, last page visited, or even last time the post count was fetched asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you will create a cookie ($_COOKIE['lastPostId']) in each customer webbrowser with the LAST ID of your posts, and, when the user return, you will read `$_COOKIE['lastPostId']` and query your database as `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id>lastPostId`